# Modifying a type after it has been created with TypeBuilder.CreateType

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm creating a dynamic class in a dynamic assembly at runtime, and want to be able to Define methods for that class on demand.

Ex.

1. Build the Type X
2. Define Method GetA on Type X
3. Create Type X
4. Call GetA
5. use same type builder for Type X
6. Define new Method GetB on Type X
7. Recreate type X, that now has both GetA and GetB

if that is impossible then I will have to build the type on demand for one of the methods, and to do that then I have to create the assembly as well, on each time.

Any Ideas,
Thanks

Comment: Can you do something similar? Execute stedp 1-3 to get type X, then execute 1, 2, 6, and 7 to get type Y (that isn't X?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create "full" methods (discoverable via reflection) - however, you can use `DynamicMethod` to associate new IL blocks with a type (primarily for scope etc). But ultimately, what you describe is a job for the DLR in 4.0 (and a language such as Iron Python; C# and VB don't add language support for *declaring* dynamic methods - only consuming them).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create the type with [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). You can build the entire type, compile the code, then load the new assembly and use the type.